# Woocommerce paypal taking return order received path Wrong

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have installed Woo Commerce and activated Paypal, after success full payment order received URL is taking wrong.

Its taking "/us/cgi-bin/http://domainname.com/checkout/order-received/1146?key=wc_order_53d8e65378df2&utm_nooverride=1"

Instead "http://domainname.com/checkout/order-received/1146?key=wc_order_53d8e65378df2&utm_nooverride=1"

Can anyone suggest how to solve this.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried myself so cannot confirm but there are suggestions to:

1) Roll back to WooCommerce V2.1.11 of the plugin or

2) Look for WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout > PayPal (standard) and then make sure that the Submission Method option is unchecked.